# The service definition selected is invalid when use https

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, https

When I try to create a new Web Service Client from a WSDL "https://localhost:8443...?wsdl" using Eclipse I get "The service definition selected is invalid"

I'm using: 
  Eclipse Version: 3.5.2
  apache-tomcat-6.0.32
  keystore generated by myself

Comment: You might be running into a SSL certificate error, hidden behind the message you see. Have a look at http://www.coderanch.com/t/468285/Web-Services/java/SSL-Web-Service-Client and see if that is applicable.

Comment: The error only appears on https? It's ok on http?

Answer (score 1):

This is my solution. 
Go to windows-> preference ->network connection ->active provider , then 
select Native. I was facing same problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing localhost with the actual IP address. I was facing the same problem and it worked for me this way